# Merge tags [broadcastreceiver] and [android-broadcast]

Tags: discussion, status-declined, tags, retag-request, synonym-request

There are two tags for android broadcast receiver. Can they be merged?

[broadcastreceiver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/broadcastreceiver) 
has ~ 8k questions

[android-broadcast](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-broadcast)
has ~ 1k questions

So can [android-broadcast](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-broadcast) tag be merged into [broadcastreceiver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/broadcastreceiver) tag?

Comment: @DavyM Ok have done what you advised.

Comment: The excerpt says "A broadcast intent on the Android platform is a special intent which is often invoked by the system on an event and catched by a BroadcastReceiver" (sic), which makes it clear that they're both different. Are you sure that both "broadcast" and "broadcastreceiver" are the same?

Comment: @BhargavRao Sir Rao. I am pretty sure they are both same. The broadcast intent is special type of intent used for the broadcast component. But broadcast receiver also falls under this broadcast intent as it receives the intent.

Comment: A broadcast isn't the same as a BroadcastReceiver. A broadcast is the action of sending an Intent, or the subject itself. A BroadcastReceiver receives a broadcast. They're part of the same topic, but they're not the same thing. A question could be about sending a broadcast without asking how to receive it.

Comment: @TheWanderer I understand their differences. But shouldn't they be under one tag. I mean just look at the questions on the android-broadcast tag. They are full of receivers questions. You cannot deny that.

Comment: It might make sense for broadcastreceiver to be synonymized against android-broadcast, but not the other way around. Not every question about broadcasts is about BroadcastReceivers, but every question about BroadcastReceivers is about broadcasts.

Comment: @TheWanderer Ok I understood your point. Thanks for your time.

Comment: @TheWanderer, in the case of synonyms, _both_ should mean the same. If the relation is just one way, then we shouldn't synonymize the tags.